# 'threading' object has no attribute 'Thread'

Tags: python, multithreading

I have imported threading module in python for doing some threading stuffs. But it says threading module has no attribute 'Thread'. What is the problem?

Comment: what is the name of your script file?

Comment: my silly mistake was I spelled `Thread` as `thread`, and I didn't notice for a while. Leaving the comment here so somebody can correct this silly mistake.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Check that you have not named your script `threading.py`

Comment: thank you man. that was such a silly mistake -- I had to say this again :)

Comment: One more thank you!

Comment: OMG :O  I was right several we made the same mistake

Comment: LOL, the filename causes python to go wild. StackOverflow exists for a reason....

Comment: my file name is thread.py. It also caused such funny error. Thank. you Pad!! saved me the day

Comment: thank you man, such a silly mistake, had to say this again :)

Comment: mate, you save lives! :))

Comment: I'm so dumb. 

Comment: :) LOL. Everyone who did the same mistake give an up for the answer

Comment: I am apparently the 104th person to have made this mistake!

Comment: oh silly python. i solved python's' mistake . :)

Comment: I am apparently the 132th person to have made this mistake!